# boost read_until stops at white space

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to setup a tcp socketing server with boost. For some reason the function `read_until` seems to be stopping at white space rather then going all the way until the delimiter.
for example:

sent

```
┼N▀]»ü rx}q╠Cä≥è┘Y\║ï2æ╨╬ΣfV╠παÇ/S┬0è3à ╫VR∞{εoÆ?LeN≡╬.lÖnÖ1⌡&âm&ù╫ä╛'°≈L▀_ °çF¿P»2ß|╪+96#3kα≥
╟¬─╣╩í▄¢hú╤fûº╢5~AcbF┌Zd╒∞?╓)a.ƒ¿B■αZº=■uΣ╔nÜ┌╬▌╝>┌iE┌y≈ÿ≤┴Kå ²å£∩¢R>╒S(y╙cPjA▀▀Z2O╓?  ÆÉ@τß╢ªy╗▒*Γ▓σ&K₧@╦╩∙⌠%ßΩ-x*Ü╞7ε_█zâ╡C
╧╩║╗Q■═TM╠<æ┤päi^▓'àiUóα<«3Çÿ ─╗E  Σ]ππa╒εk»╣╕(╔╡╙ä╝y≡╥¡╠▌╪┼¡Ö
a|MC├₧\y╚üßσ√⌡ÿ±2<æq}ÿ┌Mzçα∩òΣÆ{end}
```

recived:

```
┼N▀]»ü
```

My code that reads from the socket is

```
string read_(tcp::socket& socket, CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey *privateKey) {
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, buf, "{end}");
    string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
    std::cout << "recived:\n" << data << std::endl;
    return data
}
```

solution:

```
string read_(tcp::socket& socket, CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey *privateKey) {
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, buf, "{end}");
    streambuf::const_buffers_type buf2 = buf.data();
    string data(buffers_begin(buf2), buffers_begin(buf2) + buf.size());
    std::cout << "recived:\n" << data << std::endl;
    return data
}
```

Comment: _Don't_ treat binary data as a c-string. What does `read_until` return?

Comment: @tkausl It returns a ```const_buffers_1```. If I check the size in the debugger that has all the characters. So if my static cast won't work do you know a way to do it that will get all the characters?

Answer (score 0):

You should output the characters in a safe way, e.g. by printing each byte as 2 hex digits:

```
auto read_(tcp::socket& socket, CryptoPP::RSA::PrivateKey * /*privateKey*/) {
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    boost::asio::read_until(
        socket,
        boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(data),
        "{end}");

    std::cout << "received:\n";
    for (int ch : data) {
        std::cout << " " << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << ch;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Note that I elected to:

- omit the intermediate `streambuf`
- used the opportunity to demonstrate that you can easily use more apt data structures (`std::vector<uint8_t>`), although you can, of course, replace that with `std::string`